# new Date() en javascript me resta un dia

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con fechas, y al hacer una fecha con el metodo new Date() me resta un dia.

Mi codigo:

```
let prueba = new Date('2018-12-04')
console.log(prueba)
```

y en la consola tengo la siguiente fecha:

```
Mon Dec 03 2018 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina)
```

O sea, yo quiero que la fecha sea el 4 de diciembre y en consola tengo un dia menos.....

Desde ya gracias....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cuando creas un nuevo objeto **Date** utilizando ese formato de fecha (*aaaa-mm-dd*) toma como hora las 00:00:00 y como zona horaria por defecto la +0. Quedando conformada la fecha de la siguiente forma: 4 de diciembre de 2018 a las 0hs en zona +0.

Cuando imprimís en la consola la fecha del navegador, se ajusta a la zona horaria que tenés configurada en tu computadora, en este caso GMT-3. Al realizar este ajuste para que veas la fecha "traducida" a tu zona horaria le resta estas tres horas de diferencia y quedás con 3 de diciembre de 2018 a las 21hs en zona -3.

La forma de asegurarte que quede la fecha correcta en el **Date** es agregarle también la hora:

```
var d = new Date("2015-12-04T00:00:00");
```

Al hacerlo así el navegador asume que la hora indicada es en tu zona horaria y automáticamente la ajusta para almacenarla correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Roberto, gracias por tu respuesta. Acabo de hacerlo asi y obtengo el mismo resultado, me sigue restando un dia...

Comment: Hice la prueba y lo muestra correctamente. Te debe estar afectando algo más externo al código.

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando en el navegador o con código del lado del servidor? Si es el último caso puede ser que este tenga otra configuración diferente de zona horaria.

Comment: A mi no me funciona. Estoy trabajando directamente en el navegador... Siguiendo tus instrucciones, si el la hora pongo T03:00:00Z si me funciona correctamente. O sea que de todos modos aunque le indique la hora me hace la resta de las tres horas... Lo que me quedaria asumo es detectar la zona horaria y corregir asi

Comment: Sin la Z... La Z indica tiempo Zulú o GMT+0. Al agregarle eso "bloqueas" la conversión de zonas que hace el navegador.

Comment: Ahora si! Gracias

Answer (score 5):

Te recomiendo esta porción de código para compensar la diferencia provocada por la zona horaria que es lo que te está provocando esa diferencia de fechas:

```
let fecha = new Date('2018-12-04')
fecha.setMinutes(fecha.getMinutes() + fecha.getTimezoneOffset())
console.log(fecha)
```

Comment: Esto funciono! Gracias

Comment: Esto me funciono, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando el fecha ISO:  "2018-12-04" (The International Standard).
Dependiendo de tu zona horaria varía entre Diciembre 03 y Diciembre 04. Aunque en tu caso es Argentina, lo que debes hacer es aumentarle 1 día más a tu fecha para que te muestre le fecha exacta que deseas. Como te reitero, es estándar de Javascript.

Referencia:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Comment: Ok gracias, pero al agregarle un dia SIEMPRE me va a dar la fecha correcta o dependiendo del horario me va a dar un dia mas?